# Recyclerview layout in dialog box

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, layout, dialog

I am facing a problem while opening recyclerview in a dialog box. The layout in the recyclerview is overlapping and cutting when I open this in a dialog box same like this:

[image]

But, my original layout is look like this:

[image]

and here is the code for my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/corner_layout"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_field_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Admission No."
        android:textColor="#009EBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/r_d_field_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/r_d_field_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admission_no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="45654"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/st_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/st_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_d_field_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Student Name"
        android:textColor="#009EBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p_a_field_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/r_field_name"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Harikant Sharma"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/st_father_mother_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/r_d_field_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/admission_no" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/p_a_field_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Parents Name"
        android:textColor="#009EBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_call_st"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/r_d_field_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/r_d_field_name"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/st_father_mother_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Suresh Kumar Sharma"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_view_st_profile"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/st_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/st_name" />



    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_view_st_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_call_st"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_call_st"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:backgroundTint="#E10751"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:src="@drawable/phone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_view_st_profile"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_view_st_profile"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_view_st_profile"
        app:tint="@color/white" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: try making the text size smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you constrain both left and right, you need to set `width=0dp`

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/st_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp" <-- change to 0dp
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Harikant Sharma"
            android:textColor="#555555"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/st_father_mother_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/r_d_field_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/admission_no" />
```